# How to have Google Places Autocomplete work with AMP?

Tags: django, google-places-api, amp-html, google-amp, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to convert this homepage to AMP: [excurj.com](https://www.excurj.com). Is there a way to keep the Autocomplete feature on the hero search field ?

I saw [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/amphtml-discuss/vKWbBlSmEHc/-SkGCGm0CgAJ) question. However, I need these two scripts to make autocomplete work:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/autocomplete.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&callback=initMap&libraries=places"></script>
```

This is what's inside autocomplete.js:

```
// script to auto complete location

function initMap() {

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(-90, 91), new google.maps.LatLng(-180, 80));
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
bounds: defaultBounds
};
var input = document.getElementById('google_city_search');

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I know of:

- Put the autocomplete part of your page inside a separate page and use [`amp-iframe`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe) to show it.
- Use [`amp-list`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) together with [`amp-bind`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) to implement your own autocomplete.

As far as I know Google doesn't provide an AMP version of Place Autocomplete yet. I struggled with this myself a while ago and used the iframe approach at first. But since iframes are loaded with a noticeable delay and the autocomplete was basically the main part of the page I ended up doing it using the second method.

There is a good example of how to implement an autocomplete feature on [AMP by Examples](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/autosuggest/).

I made a modified version of that example specifically for Google Place Autocomplete, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/sryze/amp-google-places-autocomplete).

There is one downside to the second method: it is slightly slower because autocomplete requests have to go through your server before they reach Google's severs.